# Downloading Android 5.1 Source

Tags: android, android-source

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and i just followed each and every step in this [link](https://source.android.com/source/initializing.html). After installing jdk, Git, creating working directory, i want to download Android 5.1 latest revision of source .

```
$ repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b
```

what is the correct command to download 5.1. Can you tell me how much size of the source code is?

Comment: Why didn't you use `git clone https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The instructions say do this

```
repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b android-4.0.1_r1
```

But use the following link to replace `android-4.0.1_r1` with the source version of your choice.

https://source.android.com/source/build-numbers.html#source-code-tags-and-builds

Since you want the latest 5.1, that would be `android-5.1.1_r30` at the time of this post.

So, your command would be

```
ANDROID_TARGET=android-5.1.1_r30
repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b $ANDROID_TARGET
```

Comment: Thank you bro. can you tell me approximate size and if there is some interruption in download can it resume or not?

Comment: I think resumes are supported since it is Git, and maybe a few hundred Mb